# WordPress with phpMyAdmin - 404's everywhere

Tags: wordpress, plugins, phpmyadmin, http-status-code-404

So I've been trying to make several changes to a custom WordPress theme which introduces an entire overhaul of the Dashboard. I keep finding little issues with the original theme that I need to fix (not properly checking for duplicate posts when you import new ones, post metadata not getting stored correctly, posts not getting sorted into their proper categories, etc.)

As I've been working with this I've needed to look at and modify the database countless times to either see what the theme is doing to the database or fix things it screwed up. Unfortunately I was unable to install phpMyAdmin so I've been making changes by directly typing SQL and inserting it into the theme in appropriate places, then having the script `die()` so I can see the output of my SQL.

Suddenly it hit me that I could find a plugin which integrates phpMyAdmin functionality into WordPress. So I installed wp-phpMyAdmin.

Everything seems to be going well until I try to actually **DO** anything. I can view the tables, view the rows, and look at everything. But when I try to edit a row or delete a row I get redirected to a 404 error, saying that whichever part of phpMyAdmin I happened to be accessing (for example, `tbl_row_action.php`) doesn't exist. If I go directly to these pages without submitting the form to edit or delete a row then they work just fine and I receive an error message that my SQL query was blank.

Has anyone else experienced this? I really can't figure out exactly why or where it's sending a 404. It's absolutely ridiculous.

EDIT - A little further information:

I've learned that I **only** get a 404 error when phpMyAdmin calls `sql.php` with the `sql_query` parameter set

EDIT (again) - One further update:

I only get the 404 error when sql_query contains a valid query. Looking through `sql.php` (I haven't spent TOO much time looking, mind you) I do notice that it seems to parse the query and determine if you're `SELECT`ing, `DROP`ing, `DELETE`ing, etc. so they can check your user permissions. It may be related to this parsing code.

The following queries did not give me a 404:

```
test
SELECT test
SELECT test FROM test
SELECT test FROM post_meta
DELETE
DROP
DROP test
```

The following gave me a 404:

```
SELECT * FROM test
SELECT * FROM post_meta
DELETE FROM
DELETE FROM test
DELETE FROM post_meta
DROP TABLE
DROP TABLE test
```

MORE EDITS -

So at the very top of sql.php I placed this line of code:

```
die("Test");
```

It doesn't die when I make the bad queries listed above. It goes straight to the 404 message. Clearly this is something to do with WordPress's redirect script and not with phpMyAdmin

FINAL EDITS -

I've done a lot more research and been grep'ing the heck out of WordPress.

I highly suspect that I am having this issue as the result of some new WordPress security feature. Older versions of WordPress apparently used to allow SQL to be input into URL's, which posed a HUGE security risk. As a result it's understandable that they wouldn't allow SQL to be passed through URL's now. Just before the template the value of `is_404()` is being set to true. It's being set within `WP::parse_request()` (which is called by `WP::main()` which is called by `wp()` which is called within `wp-blog-header.php`)

Any time there is a suspected SQL query **ANYWHERE** in the requested URI, I get kicked to a 404 page. I would like to change this behavior while making as few modifications to WordPress core as possible. I need someone who is really good with WordPress to help me here. I presume an answer exists involving the $wp_rewrite variable, which contains a multitude of URL rewrite rules.

PROBLEM FINALLY DISCOVERED -

For anyone interested who finds this post or was following it or simply had similar issues, I finally located the source of the 404 errors. It didn't lie with WordPress at all. The problem fell to mod_security, an Apache module which prevents any requests that look suspicious (including those with SQL in the request URI)

Always remember to set your mod_security settings properly.

Comment: Why bother? Just rededicate your efforts to install phpMyAdmin. What's the problem with it?

Comment: The previous commenter is right, tell us what you mean by "I was unable to install phpMyAdmin"? If you can connect to your host through SSH, I absolutely recommend using MySQL Workbench, it's a great tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress shouldn't be interfering with phpMyAdmin, since the plugin loads it in a isolated iframe.

> As one of his specifications for the project he wants ONLY WordPress installed on his server...

The plugin is, nonetheless, still *phpMyAdmin* (albeit 'wrapped' in the WordPress UI). In other words, *you've already installed it* ;)

> ...to avoid the hassle of updating and maintaining other software...

'Software' can be a dangerous term when talking web-apps - that's not to say don't use it *at all*, but for some it can conjure up thoughts of blue screens and runtime errors ;)

In other words, just stress that PMA is simply a collection of files on the server - it has no database of it's own, it's effectively stateless, and removal is as simple as `RMD /phpmyadmin`.

> ...he wants to be able to make all necessary administrative changes from the WordPress Dashboard

Despite the points I've already made, if it is *absolutely* essential that there is database management access within the dashboard, I'm about to write a quick alternative that uses [phpMiniAdmin](http://phpminiadmin.sourceforge.net/) instead  (that's how I stumbled on this question oddly!), and I'd be happy to share it for you to try out.

Comment: The difference between installing (or, as you wished to point out, uploading - since it's just files) phpMyAdmin or installing it as a WordPress plugin is that WordPress automatically checks for updates to plugins. This way it poses less of a security risk if phpMyAdmin were never updated. As for why WordPress is interfering, WordPress uses an extremely simply .htaccess rewrite rule. ALL requests go to WordPress's index.php. Whenever the URL contained SQL I was redirected to a 404 page. I also did not see a plugin for phpMiniAdmin, but I may make one if it uses POST instead of GET

Comment: "WordPress automatically checks for updates to plugins" - true, but it still hinges on the plugin author to make the updates. Heck, that plugin is PMA 2.10.3, but we're up to 3.4.2 now! "ALL requests go to WordPress" Not quite; only requests that don't match a *real* file or folder. If you check the plugin page source, you'll see it's just an iframe that points directly to the PMA install.

Comment: That doesn't explain, then, why modifying WordPress's index.php allows me to make changes to the contents of the iframe. I put in a line such as `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '...'){ die("Yup....."); }` with the `REQUEST_URI` used by PMA for a simple task like dropping a table. Sure enough, when I try to drop a table I get a blank page that says `Yup.....`. This implies that somewhere and somehow any requests containing SQL are going to WordPress and not the plugin.

Comment: Hmm. Every request within PMA should point to a physical file (it has no rewrites of it's own), so WordPress should *never* get involved. Could you post the contents of your `.htaccess`? And when you hit a 404, I'm guessing the URI's a bit like `/wp-content/plugins/wp-phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/FILE.php?QUERY_STRING` - what is `FILE.php`?

Comment: By fluke, I've *just* stumbled on a plugin called [Adminer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adminer/), which turns out to be a fork of phpMiniAdmin!

Comment: I'll try Adminer, and if it doesn't work then I'll edit my question to post the contents of my .htaccess file and the URI which invokes the 404. Thank you.

Comment: Adminer worked perfectly =) So no need to use phpMyAdmin anymore. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

As @molnarm pointed out in the comments, why not just removed phpMyAdmin and connect to MySQL over SSH, using something like [MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/) or [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/).

You would have a much easier and faster way to interact with MySQL and could delete the nightmare that is phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Since the bounty is ending soon I suppose you're automatically going to be rewarded the +100, however I need phpMyAdmin operating as a WordPress plugin inside of the WordPress dashboard for the sake of my client. As one of his specifications for the project he wants ONLY WordPress installed on his server to avoid the hassle of updating and maintaining other software, and he wants to be able to make all necessary administrative changes from the WordPress Dashboard.